# ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available

Tags: wifi

I am running the latest version of Elementary *5.1.7 Hera* on my Dell XPS 15 but I get the message `ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available`, after about a minute when running a ping.

Internet access gets disabled even while I'm connected to WiFi.

Kindly advise what can be done to remediate this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you have hit a maximum value for a system parameter, most likely the `/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max` value. This setting is the maximum amount "receive socket memory", but further investigation will be needed.

This generally happens when one of three things is taking place:

1. the network adapter is broken
2. the network adapter is using a driver that is not 100% supported
3. the entire system is stressed out because it is mining BitCoin or something like that

You *can* look at increasing the `wmem_max` value, but it is very rarely the correct solution to a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I do have a dual boot Windows 10, and the WiFi connection never breaks on it like it does on the ElementaryOS.

I also tried to increase the value of  `wmem_max` as advised, but that didn't seen to resolve the issue.
Also ,no crypto mining on my PC for me :)

Comment: Then it sounds like you may want to confirm that you have the best driver for the device, as that would be the most likely culprit 